# Ошибка при записи в csv файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, csv

Все данные хранятся в списке словарей под названием data. При попытке записать данные в табличку возникает ошибка. Что я делаю не так?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import csv

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def get_content(html):
    soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
    trcont = soup.findAll('tr')
    data = []
    for tr in trcont:
        td_list = [t.text for t in tr.findAll('td')] # чтобы обратиться к каждому элементу cоздал список 
        # Если список пустой, пропускаем обработку текущего <tr>
        if not td_list:
            continue
        name = td_list[0]
        description = td_list[1]
        proizvoditel = td_list[2]
        data.append(
            {
            'name': name,
            'description': description,
            'proizvoditel': proizvoditel
            })
    return data


def write_csv(data):
    with open('podshipniki.scv', 'w') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(['Тип товара', 'Наименование', 'Производитель'])
        for i in data:
            writer.writerow((data['name'], data['description'], data['proizvoditel']))



def main():
    url = 'xxx'
    write_csv(get_content(get_html(url)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Текст ошибки:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\abracadabra\irbis.py", line 45, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\abracadabra\irbis.py", line 42, in main
        write_csv(get_content(get_html(url)))
      File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\abracadabra\irbis.py", line 36, in write_csv
        writer.writerow((data['name'], data['description'], data['proizvoditel']))
    TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в этой функции, в нее вы передаете `data`, которое является списком, а обращение делаете как к словарю:

```
def write_csv(data):
    with open('podshipniki.scv', 'w') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(['Тип товара', 'Наименование', 'Производитель'])
        for i in data:
            writer.writerow((data['name'], data['description'], data['proizvoditel']))
```

Попробуйте цикл так поменять:

```
        for row in data:
            writer.writerow((row['name'], row['description'], row['proizvoditel']))
```